# Is there any way to fetch data in json format from PostgreSQL table which has different field not the json data type field?

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a table in PostgreSQL which has field like id,name,city,mob
etc. i got that in PostgreSQL there is json data type in which we can
store the data in json format but I don't want to use json data type.

I want to fetch these table field (id,name,city,mob) which are normal fields not json data type field that I want in json format

I want that suppose mytable is a table which has id,name,city,mob,dob as field and
now i want to execute query like:

```
select name,city from mytable where id=5;
```

This query should return output like `{"name":"xyz","city":"abc"}`

so how can i do that and what should be the query for that?

Comment: `row_to_json()`? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

Comment: but what if i want some columns from a row?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea what you mean. `row_to_json()` will use the columns from the row. If you want a good answer, then [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. _Formatted_ text please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_to_json()`:

```
select row_to_json(t) 
from (
   select name,city from mytable 
   where id=5
) t
```

The derived table is necessary to create a record type with proper names for the columns. `row_to_json((name,city))` would not achieve this.

**Edit**:

If you want **all** columns from the table (not just two as shown in the question) then you don't need the derived table:

```
select row_to_json(mytable)
from mytable
where id = 5;
```

Comment: what if i want select * from mytable?

Comment: then use `select row_to_json(mytable) from mytable`.

Comment: this * query is working but select row_to_json(t) 
from (
   select name,city from mytable 
   where id=5
) t is not working

Comment: opps sorry it also working i did a mistake thanks @a_horse_with_no_name